# The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio

Till yesterday my webservice was running fine in my local system today when i run the Webservcie or any webproject from VS2005 i get the below error

### Server Error in '/MyWebService' Application.

The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Please help me